# One Click Payments with PayPal Payments PRO

Tags: php, api, paypal

I'm working on an event manager project and I'd like to make it so when users create their account they will have to accept a PayPal Billing Agreement. Once this happens I would like them to be able to click purchase on an event and it immediately be charged to their PayPal account.
I have PayPal Payments Pro ready to go, just have to get this working.

Is this a possibility with PayPal, or do I have to go a different route with this?

Comment: I wanted to know if this was even possible before I started.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I was thinking about too many things at once and I forgot to add the actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you can use the SetCustomerBillingAgreement API Operation to setup the billing agreement during signup. Then when charging for a payment, you can use the DoReferenceTransaction API Operation and use the Billing Agreement ID that was returned in the previous operation.